# mysql query for both distinct and sum

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a mysql fields like this:

```
url_id     time_spent
-------    ----------
120         14
120         97  
120         14
120         97
```

I want to display only 14 and 97 based on url_id(DISTINCT).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from table group by url_id,time_spent
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.url_id, a.time_spent FROM table a
```